# Install Apache Derby on CentOS 6.4

Tags: linux, centos, tomcat, jdbc, java

I'm not a Java developer, my knowledge is very limited to this topic. I want to deploy a `.war` webservice on my Tomcat server, which fails most likely because of its Derby dependency (just a guess from `catalina.log)`. So I'm now struggling with Derby installation. First of all I've been said, it's included in the newest JDK, but there was no such package available for download. This version is all I could get from `yum`:

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.1.2.el6_5-x86_64 u65-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Stupid question, but is this the JDK or just the JRE? I downloaded and extracted Derby manually, I want Tomcat to know that Derby exists. How do I do this? Hope, I haven't completely misunderstood things.

```
java org.apache.derby.tools.sysinfo
```

returns `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.derby.tools.sysinfo`

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The default package manager of Cent OS, yum doesn't have the correct JDK's in the repositiories. (didn't try with rpm though) Looking up either version of "jdk" and installing it would install only the JRE with or without some docs. Thus the solution for question above is installing JDK from the correct source: Oracle.com. (Registration is needed). It's advised to download the executable, .rpm.bin file instead of tar.gz, so it can easily be installed with:

```
chmod +x jdk6u45.rpm.bin
./jdk6u45.rpm.bin
```

JDK 6+ includes Derby and JDBC by default.